# Intermittent connection problems to web services

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I have been having intermittent errors while calling external SOAP web services where the application makes between 10-20 web service calls per user. At the moment there can be up to 40-50 concurrent users.

The architecture is as follows:

IIS Web Server with JK2 Redirector, redirects requests to Tomcat application server. This application makes the calls to the external web services via another IIS web server, again with JK2 Redirector that directs the request to another Tomcat application server which hosts the web services.

I am getting the following errors every now and again:
- socketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
- Could not invoke service. 
- SocketException: Connection reset
- SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Is there some configuration that I should be setting for connections, timeout, etc on Tomcat or perhaps the Worker redirector?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to increase the `acceptCount` https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html